# Issue with Caffe's Input layer. Could not open or find file

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm fine-tuning Alexnet caffe model on my data. I'm using "ImageData" type for Input layer. In my train.txt file (the path of which I gave to “source” in input layer), there aren’t written extensions after image names (.jpg). But in my images directory names of the images are ending with .jpg. How can I fix this? Btw, I'm not permitted to make changes on data.

```
layer {
name: "data"
type: "ImageData"
top: "data"
top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "../../../data/food-101/meta/train.txt"
    shuffle: true
    batch_size: 50
    root_folder: "../../../data/food-101/images"
    new_height: 227 
    new_width: 227 
  }
}
```

Below is the path to my images and some examples of files.

```
../../../data/food-101/images/apple_pie/

1005649.jpg
1011328.jpg
101251.jpg
1014775.jpg
```

And this is the path to train.txt file, and some lines from it:

```
../../../data/food-101/meta/train.txt

apple_pie/1005649
apple_pie/1014775
apple_pie/1026328
apple_pie/1028787
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The AlexNet files I use don't have the "root_folder" parameter; what happens when you remove that?  train.txt contains the full file list; that should be sufficient.

Comment: Also, what *does* happen when you run your code?  Please follow the posting guidelines in the intro tour.

Comment: Another possibility is that your relative path doesn't work from your execution directory.  Replace that with an absolute path -- and verify that path before you run Caffe.

Comment: Usually the path specified in the .txt file is a relative image path to the .txt file. If that’s the case, then you have to specify the root_folder field inside ‘image_data_param’. Most of the time SOURCE PATH is the same as ROOT PATH if you put your training image folder and the train.txt file in the same folder.

Comment: So you didn't think that absence of .jpg after file name may cause the problem?

Comment: I was investigating other possibilities first.  Yes, I expect that the lack of ".jpg" is your problem.  However, you said that you don't get to alter the data you're given.  Also, you still haven't supplied a reproducible problem context, so I can't check it myself.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I've already mentioned what does happen when I run the code. It's giving "Could not open or find file" error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Among other things, this includes supplying the entire error message and minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would advise you to use absolute path at first....because depending on the folder you are issuing the train command....if you use the relative path...it will be appended to your current folder...in this case...you should run the train command in meta folder